# « En + present participle » vs « pendant que »

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, participe-présent

In order to say:

> While hiking, we used to go to a little restaurant

Would I say:

1. En faisant des randonnées, nous allions à  un petit restaurant
2. Pendant que nous faisions des randonnées, nous allions à  un petit restaurant
3. Quand nous faisions des randonnées, nous allions à  un petit restaurant

I'm not sure the correctness of any of those sentences however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 is the best way to express that meaning, although "lorsque" is also an option.

*en+participle* usually imply a **mean**:

> En faisant des randonnées, je me maintenais en forme. (By going hiking, I kept in shape.)
>
> Il a résolu le problème en cognant. (He solved the issue by hitting.)
>
> Il est passé en courant. (he ran past)

"Pendant" implies that something happens at the same time as something else, usually in a different place. This may be habitual or a single occurence.

> Pendant que nous faisions des randonnées, nos ennemis complotaient contre nous. (While we hiked, our enemies plotted against us.)
>
> Pendant que je dormais, on me cambriolait. (As I slept, someone was burglarizing my home.)

Comment: Thanks for helping (plus explaining the other senetences too)!